# How do I print the 10 lines and take 30 sleep time and so on loop until EOF

Tags: python

```
f = open('test.csv', 'r')
for line in f:
    print(line)
f.close()
```

my output should be like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

10 sec sleep time

```
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
```

and so on until EOF

Comment: And what have you tried?  This is not hard.

Comment: A combination of `enumerate`, the modulo operator and an if-block should help.

Comment: Use time.spleep https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep

Comment: in your title you want to sleep 30 second and in your eleporation you want to sleep 10sec ?

Answer (score 3):

All you need is a line counter.  `enumerate` can do that.

```
f = open('test.csv','r')
for n,line in enumerate(f):
    print(line)
    if n % 10 == 9:
        time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works using the while loop and readlines method.

```
with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        i = 0
        while i < len(lines):
            print(' '.join(lines[i:i+10]))
            time.sleep(10)
            i += 10
```